# How to build the best bang for yhe buck uhf vhf antenna or should i just buy one

Tags: antenna, diy, vhf, uhf

Help with antenna build what makes up a great antenna what can I use for elements and would a dush network dish be good reflector and how to wire the elements like the copper to one side and the shielding wires to the other elements and do reflectors get wired? I have stations directly east and directly west both in the 35-55 mile range.. I'm ordering a balun asap.. I been using the big energy drink cans as elements.. would the copper wire in rg6 coax work as bow tie elements? I seen yagi made with measuring tape and reflectors.. idk I'm kinda lost just trying different things to see what works and does a diplexer actually work to hook up two antenna to my tv? The diplexer says uhf/vhf in and sat in then tv out so any channel that's actual channel 10 and under is vhf? Cause I think all my antenna stations put out uhf I don't think I get vhf around here thanks alot

Comment: TV antennas need to have quite wide bandwidth compared to amateur radio antennas, a lot of work goes into optimising them for bandwidth, and the designs are a bit different for this reason too. If you want reliable reception for your local part of UHF, or VHF, best to buy something available there.

Comment: Please reformat your question so it is easier to read. See [this portion of the Help section](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question is in regard to to television reception.  Assuming that's the case let's take each of your many questions one at a time.

> what makes up a great antenna

Good performance is the short answer.  There are many factors involved in achieving good performance.  An important factor for the frequencies you're concerned about is antenna height.  A simple antenna at great height will likely perform better than a sophisticated antenna close to the ground.

> what can I use for elements

Almost any good conductor.  Aluminum is common.  Stainless steel as well.

> would a dush[sic] network dish be good reflector

Unlikely.  While it's certainly possible to increase gain with a dish, you also need to come up with a feed horn for the frequencies of interest.  Without a feed horn precisely positioned, filtered and amplified a dish won't achieve much.

> copper to one side and the shielding wires to the other elements

Most antenna use some form of connector that routes the coaxial conductors to the elements.  Often there are other devices between the connector and the antenna as well: impedance matching, filters, etc.  That said you have the basic idea correct: the center conductor and shield are connected to opposing elements.

> would the copper wire in rg6 coax work as bow tie elements?

Yes, although the 18 AWG center conductor is pretty thin for the application.  Difficult to imagine a ridged antenna structure using this.

> does a diplexer actually work to hook up two antenna to my tv?

Depends on the sort of antennas.  A diplexer can combine and segregate signals from different bands, typically satellite and VHF/UHF.  If the two antennas are receiving the same band a passive diplexer can't segregate them.

> any channel that's actual channel 10 and under is vhf

"Channel 10" is different frequencies in different regions.  VHF is 30MHz-300MHz.

In the US channel 10 is 192-198MHz, so it is within the VHF band.

> should i just buy one

Yes, you should.  TV antenna design is involved due to the broad range of frequencies, durability requirements and safety.  Given the low cost of commercial antennas it is hard to recommend fabricating your own.  For your part the things to focus on are achieving as much height as possible, ensuring good feed line quality and making the antenna system safe from lighting or contacting live electrical wires.